# Change Azure Subscription/tenant in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, azure-identity

I recently migrated my azure functions project from **.net core 3.1** to **.net 6** and thus, to VS 2022. I am using the Nuget **Azure.Identity** package to authenticate to other azure services. When running my app from windows terminal, I can choose the right subscription/tenant using
`az account set -s oneOfMySubs`. Then, the defaultcredential class in my code picks up the correct CLI credential from the chain as expected from [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential).

However, when debugging my app inside VS, I am getting error message
`Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. The server is not currently configured to accept this token.`

I suspect, that VS picks up my account's default subscription, which is not the one I am running my connected services in.

**How can I change the used subscription context within VS 2022?**

As it seems MS has retired the  [Azure node in Server Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-virtual-machines-access-from-server-explorer?view=vs-2022), , I see no chance to do so.

Comment: The subscription doesn't matter, only the tenant does. Have you tried configuring the tenant ids to DefaultAzureCredential? You can also try using some of the CLI credentials directly to check if that particular credential is the issue or if the DefaultAzureCredential is using some other credential that you don't expect.

Comment: When debugging in vscode it works, because there I can directly use the CLI credential. 
What do you mean exactly with configuring tenantId to defaultcredential? Use local.settings?

Comment: I mean that you can construct a credential like this: `new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { })` and in the options there are several properties that allow you to define the tenant id for e.g. Visual Studio authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @juunas for your help. This is the result, that I came up with and your comment was very useful to get there.

```cs
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
{
    VisualStudioTenantId = config.TenantId 
});
var tokenRequestContext = new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://management.core.windows.net/" });
var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);
var _credentials = new TokenCredentials(token.Token);
```

Later, I am using this token to authorize to some azure services

```
var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(_credentials)

var factories = await client.Factories.ListByResourceGroupAsync(config.ResourceGroupName);
```

Comment: You can also add an environment variable to your system or to you local json settings

    "AZURE_TENANT_ID": "<tenant-guid>"

Comment: This is a work around and not an actual fix. Is this reported at microsoft's github? I am currently having a similar issue.

Comment: I don't think so, I am not aware, that this is being handled already